# How to create a segue on pressing a UIButton that's locted inside a custom UIView with storyboard in XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue, custom-view

Normally (when using XCode storyboard to create an UI) ctrl-drag does the job of creating a segue to an other view controller. Works perfect with an UIButton.

But how to create a segue with ctrl-drag if the UIButton is located inside a custom view (subclass of UIView that is) ?

```
import UIKit

// class KachelView is used several times in 
// the main storyboard on entry panel.

@IBDesignable
class KachelView: UIView {
// normal stuff here
// XIB file contains a UIButton that is 
// to ignite a segue in the outer view
}
```

Is there a way to do this inside the storyboard or am I to do it in code?

Comment: Can't you ctrl-drag from your desired button in storyboard?

Comment: The UIButton is part of the custom UIView. This seems to prevent using it as normal UIButton with ctrl-drag stuff. Does not work

Comment: Solved problem using the answer from @Edgar plus some additional ado. I subclassed from UIControl instead of UIView. So I could use the notifier/observer-mechanism of UIKit to create an event inside KachelView that could be subscribed in the storyboard class. Then segue by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not seem to be possible to create a Segue via Interface Builder from a Designable View. Think of a Designable View just as a way to render the view within the Interface Builder so that it looks more like what you get on the simulator or a real device.

In alternative, create an `IBAction` on your custom view (`KachelView`) and delegate back to the view controller who owns it (set the view controller as delegate when setting up the view). Then you can easily perform a segue programatically using:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: <YOUR_IDENTIFIER>, sender: self)
```